# Dynamic text based on date EDT & PDT

Tags: php, datetime

I need to change some button text with PHP at 10am EDT tomorrow and 10am PDT tomorrow.

Will this work and / or is there a more concise way to do it?

```
$now = time();

$edt = new DateTime("2022-03-30 10:00 EDT");
$pdt = new DateTime("2022-03-30 10:00 PDT");

$edtTS = $edt->getTimestamp();
$pdtTS = $pdt->getTimestamp();

if (in_array($eventId, $edtEvents)) { // this just checks if the event is on the east coast
  if ($now > $edtTS) {
    $btnText = "BUY PRESALE";
  } else {
    $btnText = $status;
  }
}

if (in_array($eventId, $pdtEvents)) { // this just checks if the event is on the west coast
  if ($now > $pdtTS) {
    $btnText = "BUY PRESALE";
  } else {
    $btnText = $status;
  }
}
```

Comment: WHy not just `$now = time();` and `$edt = strtotime("2022-03-30 10:00 EDT");`

Comment: There are ways to write it in a more DRY fashion, but it looks like it should work fine. Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your comment. Yes `$now=time()` is better. No problem locally on the west coast, but I wonder if time() is relative to the server rendering that time or how to think of that so my brain doesn't melt :)

Comment: Timestamps are based on seconds since the epoch in UTC, so when you enter the timezone explicitly in the time it will convert. This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison based on timestamps works. Objects of type DateTime are directly comparable. The comparison works correctly even if the objects have different time zones. Example:

```
$edt = new DateTime("2022-03-30 10:00 EDT");  //Eastern Daylight Time
$edtAsUTC = new DateTime("2022-03-30 14:00 UTC");

var_dump($edt == $edtAsUTC, $edt < $edtAsUTC, $edt > $edtAsUTC);
//bool(true) bool(false) bool(false)
```

Try it on https://3v4l.org/Zh0je

Instead of $now = time(); a DateTime object can also be created for now and used for the comparisons.

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
//..
if ($now > $edt) {
```